# How to setup WebStorm for Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, webstorm

i'm in trouble of setting Webstorm for MEAN app

To be honest, this is my first meeting with JS and I can't understand how to correctly get syntax highlight and IDE help

What should I do after these steps?:

1. Installed Webstorm
2. Installed Node.js
3. Installed Mongo DB

Now I’m really confused because of the need to install **Node.js packages, @types, ECMA standarts, javascript libraries, babel library**

Because...
IDE asks me to use **export {something}** but when I'm running it it doesn't work,
AND when I use **module.exports = function f**, other modules doesn't see my function, but it compiles!
Also, **exports** without **module.** doesn't work.

Am I really should install all of these things or there any other more simple ways?

Comment: Jetbrains has a guide for setting up node.js projects in webstorm:; https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/developing-node-js-applications.html

Comment: WebStorm is extremely `wrist agile`, giving you both flexibility and rigor.  The price to pay is the learning curve, i suggest you grow into mastering that product.  The rewards will be significant over the long run.  Follow the guide linked by @Merijndk to start.